# React : Open/close react-colorful picker

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using [react-colorful](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-colorful#getting-started) to get colors HEX code.
I would want to show this component when **the color's box is clicked**, and hide it when clicked outside of it, kinda like the color picker Chrome is using (ex `<input type="color" />` )

How to do so ?

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-colorful-demo-forked-wwxq2?file=/src/App.js:308-322

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { HexColorPicker } from "react-colorful";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [color, setColor] = useState("#b32aa9");

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setColor(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <HexColorPicker color={color} onChange={setColor} />

      //Click on this box to show the picker <div className="value" style={{ borderLeftColor: color }}>
        Current color is {color}
      </div>
      <input value={color} onChange={handleChange} />
      <div className="buttons">
        <button onClick={() => setColor("#c6ad23")}>Choose gold</button>
        <button onClick={() => setColor("#556b2f")}>Choose green</button>
        <button onClick={() => setColor("#207bd7")}>Choose blue</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first, you should have to declare a state which tracks whether the color box is open or not like

```
const [open, setopen] = useState(false);
```

Now add an event handler on the div of the box which toggles the state from false to true and true to false.

```
const openBox = () => {
    setopen(!open);
  }
```

Now in your return statement, add a conditional to open or close colorBox. if clicked on that div which holds the onClick method.

```
<div className="App">
      {open &&<HexColorPicker color={color} onChange={setColor} />
      }
      

      <div onClick={() => openBox()}className="value" style={{ borderLeftColor: color }}>
        Current color is {color}
      </div>
```

Now if you click on the div which contains the onClick method, it will open the colorBox and on pressing again it will close it.

Comment: Thank you. But if your solution, in order to close the picker, you have to click on that very box. If the user clicks outside the box, it will not close. The answer above solves this. Anyway thank you.

Comment: for that, you can set another closing function on the most parent div , the concept is exactly the same. it depends where you apply the onClick event. Anyway, i am glad you got the solution.Happy Coding!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following example (from https://codesandbox.io/s/opmco found in Code Recipes)

```js
import React, { useCallback, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { HexColorPicker } from "react-colorful";

import useClickOutside from "./useClickOutside";

export const PopoverPicker = ({ color, onChange }) => {
  const popover = useRef();
  const [isOpen, toggle] = useState(false);

  const close = useCallback(() => toggle(false), []);
  useClickOutside(popover, close);

  return (
    <div className="picker">
      <div
        className="swatch"
        style={{ backgroundColor: color }}
        onClick={() => toggle(true)}
      />

      {isOpen && (
        <div className="popover" ref={popover}>
          <HexColorPicker color={color} onChange={onChange} />
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

useClickOutside.js

```js
import { useEffect } from "react";

// Improved version of https://usehooks.com/useOnClickOutside/
const useClickOutside = (ref, handler) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    let startedInside = false;
    let startedWhenMounted = false;

    const listener = (event) => {
      // Do nothing if `mousedown` or `touchstart` started inside ref element
      if (startedInside || !startedWhenMounted) return;
      // Do nothing if clicking ref's element or descendent elements
      if (!ref.current || ref.current.contains(event.target)) return;

      handler(event);
    };

    const validateEventStart = (event) => {
      startedWhenMounted = ref.current;
      startedInside = ref.current && ref.current.contains(event.target);
    };

    document.addEventListener("mousedown", validateEventStart);
    document.addEventListener("touchstart", validateEventStart);
    document.addEventListener("click", listener);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", validateEventStart);
      document.removeEventListener("touchstart", validateEventStart);
      document.removeEventListener("click", listener);
    };
  }, [ref, handler]);
};

export default useClickOutside;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Exactly what I wanted. But I have a question as a beginner. Isn't the use of ref a little bit too much for that kind of functionnality ?